# React native navigation from seperated class files

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm just started learning React Native. Used create-react-native-app. Code works as well. I can navigate my screen to Details from HomeScreen.

**App.js** file:

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    _onPressButton() {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('DetailsScreen');
    }
    return (
      // Views
    );
  }
}

class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      // Views
    );
  }
}

const RootStack = StackNavigator(
  {
    HomeScreen: { screen: HomeScreen, },
    DetailsScreen: { screen: DetailsScreen, },
  },
  { initialRouteName: 'HomeScreen', }
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <RootStack />;
  }
}
```

Then i separated HomeScreen and DetailScreen into individual js file from App.js file. And now i am unable to navigate them. What makes it unable to navigate them?

**App.js** file:

```
import ...    
import HomeScreen from './screens/homeScreen'; 
import DetailsScreen from './screens/detailsScreen';

const RootStack = StackNavigator(
  {
    HomeScreen: {screen: HomeScreen,},
    DetailsScreen: {screen: DetailsScreen,}
  },
  { initialRouteName: 'HomeScreen', }
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <RootStack />;
  }
}
```

**HomeScreen.js** file

```
import ...

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    _onPressButton() {
        Alert.alert('You tapped the button!');
        this.props.navigation.navigate('DetailScreen');
    }
    render() {
        return (
            // View
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error? The only potential issue that I can see from the code above is: `import HomeScreen from './screens/homeScreen;'`, did you name the `homeScreen.js` with a lowercase `h`?

Comment: Yep with a lowercase.

Comment: Error is "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation')"

Comment: Another potential issue is probably inside `HomeScreen.js` file where you used `this.props.navigation.navigate.navigate('Detail')`, there should be only one `navigate` but you used 2 and the detail screen name in `App.js` file is `DetailsScreen` but here you used `Detail`

Comment: Sorry mistaken. But still same ... :(

Comment: If this doesn't work, I have no idea why it's wrong..... simply change your `homeScreen.js` to `HomeScreen.js` and `detailsScreen.js` to `DetailsScreen.js` to keep the class names and the files names consistent

Comment: Add your code for how `_onPressButton` is being used. I've seen many similar questions and with the way you wrote it, it looks like you may have refactored and used `_onPressButton` in your `onPress` like this: `onPress={this._onPressButton}` in which case it would be unbound and not have access to the correct `this` context. I also find it strange that you have `_onPressButton` defined inside your `render` prior to splitting the code up into separate files. My gut tells me that you made changes along the way and just didn't realize it.